# UITextView clear selection when touching outside

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

There is UITextView which is selectable but not editable.
When I highlight text and touch outside the selection is not cleared.
I tried to use UIMenuControllerWillHideMenu, it helps to clear selection when I touch other as the menu controller dismiss. But the problem is when I change the selection the selection is cleared because the menu controller dismissed and re appear after the selection modification.
Has anyone workaround this problem too?

Comment: Are you talking about touching outside the text view, or outside the selection but inside the text view? What do yo mean by *when I touch other*?

Comment: I mean touching outside the text view. I am thinking of adding touch down action for every other views. Better workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Add UITapGestureRecognizer and call endEditing:YES on your UITextView.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTextViewTap:)];
 
- (void)onTextViewTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    if (tapGesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            self.textView.selectedTextRange = nil;
    }
}
```